# Ascending Numbers in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the numbers in ascending order. When I go to console and type a number, the number prints but not in ascending order, just the number i put in.What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
public class BigLittle{
   public static void main(String[]args){
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

      int a=0;
      int b=0;
      int c=0;

      System.out.print("Enter 3 Numbers");
      a=in.nextInt();
      b=in.nextInt();
      c=in.nextInt();

      if (a>b&&b>c)
         System.out.print(c);
      if (a>c) {
        System.out.print(b);
        System.out.print(a); 
      }

      if (b<a&&b<c)
        System.out.print(b);
      else {
        System.out.print(a);
        System.out.print(c);
      }
      if (c>a&&a<b)
         System.out.print(a);
      if (b<c){
         System.out.print(c+b+a);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What numbers are you putting in?

Comment: The user puts in the number. I just tried random numbers but it didnt work

Comment: What numbers did you put in, when it didn't work?

Comment: Rather than use complicated if/else statements that wouldn't scale beyond a few numbers you should add the numbers to a collection like an ArrayList and sort it using Collections.sort() then iterate through the list and print the numbers.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 2):

Put the numbers from input into a List and then sort the List:

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter 3 Numbers: ");
    list.add(in.nextInt());
    list.add(in.nextInt());
    list.add(in.nextInt());

    Collections.sort(list);

    for ( Integer i : list )
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if `c = 8`, `b = 4` and `a = 1` if will print 13 with that line `System.out.print(c+b+a);`

Also, if `a=b=c` nothing prints, or any combinaisons that `a=b`, `b=c` or `a=c`, there is some printing undefined.

If you want a simple architecture, try to put an array or 3 variables to put the values in it and then print only at the end of the computation.

Answer (score 0):

**With three arguments**

If you enter three numbers, it means that you have 6 possible permutations 3!=3*2*1) which lead to 6 if-cases to be handle:

1. `a>b && b>c` // by transitivity `a>c`. Which mean that `a>b && b>c` is same as saying `a>b && b>c && a>c`
2. `a>b && b<=c && c>b`
3. `a>b && b<=c && c<=b`
4. `a<=b && b>c && c>b`
5. `a<=b && b>c && c<=b`
6. `a<=b && b<=c` // by transitivity `a<=c` Which mean that `a<=b && b<=c` is same as saying `a<=b && b<=c && a<=c`

Translated into code, it looks like (I let you complete the `TODO`):

```
if (a > b) {
    if (b > c) {
        // 1. a>b && b>c
        // TODO complete here
    } else {
        if (c>b) {
            // 2. a>b && b<=c && c>b
            // TODO complete here
        } else {
            // 3. a>b && b<=c && c<=b
        }
    }
} else {
    if (b > c) {
        if (c > b) {
            // 4. a<=b && b>c && c>b
            // TODO complete here
        } else {
            // 5. a<=b && b>c && c<=b
        }
    } else {
        // 6. a<=b && b<=c
        // TODO complete here
    }
}
```

What's wrong in your code?

- if `a>b && b>c`, then is implies `a>c`. It is what we call `transitivity`. So if your
  first `if(a>b && b>c)` is `true`, the second `if(a>c)` will be also `true`.
- `c+b+a` is an addition (when the type is `Int`), so `print(c+b+a)` makes no sense to me when sorting `a`,`b` and `c`.
- what are you doing when `a=b` or `b=c` or `a=c`? Your code will not print anything
- if `a<b`, `a<c` and `b<c` then you will print `a`,`b` and again `a`, and then `c+b+a`.
- ...

**With n arguments/inputs**

Now imagine that your user has to enter 10 or even worst 1000 numbers. This nested if-then-else would not be humanly readable. 
A better solution is to store into an array and then sort this array, like `Collections.sort(yourArrayToSort);`

*Reference*: [Java Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: thank you, after midnight is definitely to late to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

For three distinct numbers `a, b, c` there are 6 possible permutations:

```
1 2 3
1 3 2
2 1 3
2 3 1
3 1 2
3 2 1
```

Let's start by using the relationship between `a & b` to partition these into 2 sets

```
a < b 
    1 2 3
    1 3 2
    2 3 1    
a > b
    2 1 3
    3 1 2
    3 2 1
```

Now let's further divide these 2 sets by considering the relationship between `b & c`:

```
a < b 
  b < c
    1 2 3
  b > c
    1 3 2
    2 3 1    
a > b
  b < c
    2 1 3
    3 1 2
  b > c
    3 2 1
```

We see that in cases where `(a < b and b < c)` and `(a > b and b > c)` we can uniquely determine the ordering. For the remaining cases we need to consider the relationship between `a & c`

```
a < b 
  b < c
    1 2 3
  b > c
    a < c
      1 3 2
    a > c
      2 3 1    
a > b
  b < c
    a < c
      2 1 3
    a > c
      3 1 2        
  b > c
    3 2 1
```

From this we can develop the following pseudocode:

```
if a < b
  if b < c
    order: a b c
  else 
    if a < c
      order: a c b
    else
      order: c a b
else
  if b < c
    if a < c
      order: b a c
    else
      order: b c a
  else
    order: c b a
```

Which you should be able to turn into Java code.